# BASH sh scriptin

Tags: unix, unixodbc

I want to start BASH shell scripting but my computer run on Windows 7 (64 bit). 
Is there a way to download UNIX without having to change my operating system.
How do I go abobut downloading UNIX.
Thanks

Comment: UNIX is a standard for an operating system to which Windows does not conform. `bash` on the other hand is a shell which runs on many platforms, and there are many shells other than bash such as `tcsh` and `zsh`, each of which have their advantages. It's not possible to "download UNIX" per-se.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) ? It is

> a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows and is about the closest you are going to get to Unix environment on Windows.

You might be interested in software such [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) which allows you to run a virtual environment inside of your host OS or look into live CD/USB.

A third option would be to dual boot OS, multiple OS can be installed on your hard drive and you choice which one you boot into  start up.

Comment: There's also [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) as a way of managing your VirtualBox instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). It is a minimalist GNU implementation that works on windows. It has it's own repositories for tools, build system, etc.